# Email Extraction with POP and putting a read flag

Tags: c#, asp.net, openpop

Is there any way I can raise a read flag once an email is read using openpop in C#?

I have used `openpop.dll` in my program. I just don't know how to put up a read flag once an email is read.

Comment: You need to provide more details in order to receive any useful help. What envionment are you working in? Do you have a targeted framework version? What have you tried so far? Any sample code?

Answer (score 2):

No; the POP protocol does not support that.

Use IMAP.